# Typescript map specific keys in object

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and want to write a pretty simple generic function - it gets an object (possibly partial), gets a list of keys and maps the specified keys (if they exist) to a different value, the rest of the values need to stay the same. I want all that to be type safe.

So in case I have a type:

```ts
interface User {
  userID: string;
  displayName: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL: string;
}
```

I want to be able to have a function `mapper` which will take an object of type `Partial<User>` and then a list of keys, like `"displayName" | "photoURL"` and, for instance, capitalize their property values, and leave the rest of the properties untouched.

Here are some examples of input/output:

```ts
// INPUT
const fullUser: User = {
    userID: "aaa",
    displayName: "bbb",
    email: "ccc@ddd.com",
    photoURL: "https://eee.fff",
}

const partialUser = {
    userID: "ggg",
    photoURL: "https://hhh.iii",
}

// OUTPUT
const o1 = capsMapper<User, "displayName" | "userID">(fullUser);
const o2 = capsMapper<User, "displayName" | "userID">(partialUser);

// o1 should be
{
    userID: "AAA",
    displayName: "BBB",
    email: "ccc@ddd.com",
    photoURL: "https://eee.fff",
}

// o2 should be
{
    userID: "GGG",
    photoURL: "https://hhh.iii",
}
```

So I wrote this simple generic function:

```ts
const mapper = <Type, Keys extends keyof Type>(data: Partial<Type>) => {
  ???
}
```

and was hoping to call it like `mapper<User, "displayName" | "photoURL">(myObject)` but I cannot find a way to implement the function body. The problem is, when I'm iterating over the keys of the passed object, **I cannot find a way to check if the key is amongst the `Keys` type passed as a generic type**.
I also tried to have an additional parameter in the function:

```ts
const mapper = <Type, Keys extends keyof Type>(data: Partial<Type>, keys: Keys) => {
```

or even

```ts
const mapper = <Type, Keys extends keyof Type>(data: Partial<Type>, keys: Keys[]) => {
```

but still checking the key of the passed (possibly partial) object results in compiler errors.

Is it possible to implement such a function?

Comment: "results in compiler errors" can you give a [mre] that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: And right now you're saying you want to captialize the *keys*.  Is that really what you want?  If you actually want to captialize the property *values*, you should [edit] the question to say this.  Ideally you'd give sample inputs and outputs also.

Comment: If you could be more specific with your requirements it would be helpful.  One could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4xGvW), but maybe that's overkill in the typings, since it takes into account situations where the input properties are narrower than `string` and then get widened to `string`.  And I'm just assuming you're capitalizing values and not keys.  And I'm assuming you want to reject properties whose value types aren't strings or undefined.  Etc etc etc.  More info, pls.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz I have added input and output examples, thanks for your feedback! It doesn't make sense to give examples of compile errors because I was just trying out every crazy piece of syntax that came to my mind - that's what we programmers do when we want to get something working quickly in an unfamiliar new programming language :)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wRlr5m) meet your needs?  You definitely need to add parameters representing the keys whose values you want to map, since that's the only thing that makes sense at runtime (TS types are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the compiled JS, so that function call would look like `capsMapper(fullUser)` and there's no way to divine which keys you care about from that).

Comment: Okay you already accepted another answer so I'm not going to spend more time here.

Comment: @jcalz your answer is more precise, just post it so that I can accept it, it should not go uncredited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to pass in actual key string arguments into the `capsMapper()` function.  The TypeScript compiler is happy to deal with [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters like `K extends keyof T`, but the static type system, including generics, is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript is emitted to JavaScript, which is what actually runs at runtime.  If you don't have any *values* of type `K`, then you're probably not going to be able to do anything with them at runtime.  So instead of `<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T) => ...` we'll need something like `<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T, ...keys: K[]) => ...`.

Here's one possible implementation of `capsMapper`:

```
const capsMapper = <T extends Partial<Record<K, string>>, K extends keyof T>(
  data: T, ...keys: K[]
) => {
  const d: Omit<T, K> = data;
  const mapped: { [P in K]?: string } = {};
  for (const k of keys) {
    const v = data[k];
    if (typeof v === "string") {
      mapped[k] = v.toUpperCase();
    }
  }

  type WidenString<T> = T extends string ? string : T;
  return { ...d, ...mapped } as { 
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? WidenString<T[P]> : T[P] 
  }; 
}
```

This might be overkill in terms of the typings, but I'll explain it.  We only accept as `data` an object of type `T` whose keys of type `K` have `string` or `undefined` values.  Then we take `data` and widen its type from `T` to `Omit<T, K>`... this is just saying "let's ignore any keys of `data` that are in `K`" because we're going to overwrite these anyway.  We assign this to `d` for ease of use.

Then we make an object for just the mapped properties called `mapped`, whose type is essentially `Partial<Record<K, string>>`, and for each `k` in the `keys` array, we captialize any string properties we find and put it into `mapped` at the same key.

Finally we [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `d` and `mapped` into a new object and return it.  The type of that output would be naturally seen as `Omit<T, K> & Partial<Record<K, string>>`, which is correct, but not as specific as you might like.  That's because every key in `keys` would be seen as possibly missing, even if you know for a fact that it existed in `data`.

To make it more specific, we need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that it is actually of type `{ [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? WidenString<T[P]> : T[P] }`, a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) very much like `T` (the type of `data`) except that any mapped string properties are widened to `string` via the `WidenString<T>` [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  This is important in the case that your original `T` type had properties of string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types); if you uppercase those, you will not get the same type out.

Here let's test it and I'll show the possible need for that later:

```
const fullUser: User = {
  userID: "aaa",
  displayName: "bbb",
  email: "ccc@ddd.com",
  photoURL: "https://eee.fff",
}

const partialUser: Partial<User> = {
  userID: "ggg",
  photoURL: "https://hhh.iii",
}

const o1 = capsMapper(fullUser, "displayName", "userID");
/* const o1: {
    userID: string;
    displayName: string;
    email: string;
    photoURL: string;
} */
console.log(o1)
/* { "userID": "AAA", "displayName": "BBB",
  "email": "ccc@ddd.com", "photoURL": "https://eee.fff" }  */

const o2 = capsMapper(partialUser, "displayName", "userID");
/* const o2: {
    userID?: string | undefined;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
    email?: string | undefined;
    photoURL?: string | undefined;
} */

console.log(o2);
/*  { "userID": "GGG", "photoURL": "https://hhh.iii" } */
```

That looks reasonable, I think.  The output looks right, and the types are the same... `o1` is still a `User`, and `o2` is still a `Partial<User>`.  In the case where we have literal types, though, this happens:

```
interface Foo {
  a?: "x" | "y"
}
const foo: Foo = { a: "x" };
const o3 = capsMapper(foo, "a");
/* const o3: {
    a?: string | undefined; // this is not "x" | "y" anymore, so o3 is not a Foo
} */
console.log(o3)
// {"a": "X"}
```

Here `o3` has an `a` property which is `"X"` in uppercase.  That means `o3` is not a valid `Foo`, whose `a` property can only be `"x"` or `"y"` in lowercase.  And that's why I have that `WidenString<T>` type in there.  It turns the input type `{a?: "x" | "y"}` into the output type `{a?: string}`.

If you don't expect this kind of thing to happen, you could make the typing simpler by writing instead:

```
return { ...d, ...mapped } as T;
```

and then `o3` would be claimed by the compiler to be of type `Foo` when it isn't.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#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-ATwABMQXkIUMB7qaV6sgutzh3UBgBM2uiAhbA-28jZsZHUSBwHIChDuG8qyPISjcGOJKTkg06sLOTwmGhf6kPewKPvWTwvm+Zp2kRISYKRf6+i25q5F2nbdtsQHkAAjGM8D0EwjSsF4-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-jqMObTX0hG5HlW95lGEPOaUABqPL6vqgJAsAhqgmBgOmEJxey1BSM6ohtYoziYqwlBDMQnO0KxfMcWMfBknYkgyKBMFqBQmg6Obx0WFYhcUqsrjuJ4Ph+IEwRILyERRF08RJBwKQITVzT5IUxRdCShzMjVQpNIprTtJ03R3fSowThMHwzOw8wS0sKzd+8Zk1Xc2Rt38V0XF46IQLcnAPM8x1vITZmz78JwAkCoLNdCsLwldqLpAAaQa+WIcR4mOsSMY-BFRF0mjSTajJmSsg5FyHkYR+Sd0FI0MQIoxRMibABAMEIsahnDM-RCKk5YplWtFSAVD9xGXoXeKGOEmH-h8uadstEs7TAHO1Vgo4yETg+IFOcC4RbLimF1HS25dySPSAdY8Z4LxiCvOQG88jMIsKso8Iq74TSfjKtgci1UJatTAmOSCpdlBwTGAhURqF0KaOupZXCujYYEQRsRUimATEcKQNRXg3Daa0CYrzdizUuJ8N4pFGh3UICiWBjOIK-0xZyVCYxQRHV3R2j8AAckkLtNGIS6rhP5hCLw5ilAxP4nEnSiS+qpNNOLBiI1pBQTArBcMlgcn5MKc9JAaN0aYzDkzchssnjsz1lTGm6Tpj40ZvjOxrNJnkw3iUq2ZSOKC3IMLUWKs5lW0WbsxCdplh2gAIRpC8AQJAgg5yiWcA8kYCQYhWxCCAJAPQaQ6ziJ-MEbAf5wiSK2FQIIsy8BjIwAAokgaFKgVC5BUH6YYQA)

Answer (score 2):

```
function mapperArray<T, FilteredProp extends keyof T>(obj: Partial<T>, keyList: Array<keyof T>) {
    const a:any = {};
    (new Set(keyList.filter(key => key in obj))).forEach(key => a[key] = obj[key])
    return a as Pick<T, FilteredProp>;
}
const a = {
    prop1: "dshfyuhe",
    prop2: 154
};
const b = mapperArray<typeof a, 'prop2'>(a, ['prop2']);
console.log(b.prop2);
```

this is closest i could come up with. I hope this meet requirement, i also know that this can be improved further but currently i doesn't have knowledge and time.

I could not write it in comment with correct formatting so pasting here.

Comment: Thanks! Your implementation is not what I needed, but that is totally my fault, I was not clear enough in my question, I will update it now. However, most importantly, your answer gave me some hints in which direction to go!

Comment: I have added some examples and made the task description clearer. Just in case you want to update your implementation so that the rest of the people reading this in future don't consider it "wrong", it actually gave me some nice hints, as I wrote above.